# How to keep shirt tucked in while skiing?

Tags: clothing, sports

When I go skiing I usually wear a two-part ski suit. I do not have any special ski underwear. I often face the problem that the shirt that I wear underneath slips out of the pants because of large range of motion even though they are not particularly short. My back, esp. kidneys, get cold then.

How do I prevent this? I have tried safety pins, but they put too much stress in a small spot and just ripped the cloth.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that an elastic band could be attached to your shirt and to your pants, so it stretches but gets pulled back down. However, I can't quite picture how to implement it so I didn't write this as an Answer.

Comment: Put the hook part of hook-and-loop fasteners on the shirt, if the weave of the pants sticks to that.

Comment: you can use suspenders clipped to your socks: keeps shirt down and socks up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motorcyclists encounter a similar issue, and to work around the problem many jackets have a length of stretchy Lycra style fabric sewn onto the bottom of the jacket. It bears half a zip, and the other half of the zip is attached to the trousers. Zipping them together keeps the riders back covered with fabric, handy for a variety of things, including protection from cold and preventing the jacket from riding up exposing bare skin in an accident situation

Here we see the idea, these pants are sold standalone so they just come with a built in zip and a loose part, attaching the loose part to a jacket that doesn’t have one is an exercise for the user.

[image]

And here’s a jacket (different manufacturer hence different zip appearance) featuring the other side of the connection.. in the case where the built in zip was compatible you’d just zip them together. If the pants and jacket were different makes you’d replace the jacket size zip with the loose bit of the pants zip. the black fabric bit is stretchy:

[image]

You could try modifying your skiwear in a similar way. If you use Velcro rather than a zip, be sure to sew the hard scratchy side of the Velcro so it faces away from your skin in normal use (general rule of Velcro, if you’re arranging it a way where misali*ment means it could touch you, make sure it’s the soft side touching you)

---

Another option to consider, like babies wear suits that have poppers to attach the front to the back in the crotch region, consider modifying or extendin your shirt so you can fasten the front to the back between your legs. Alternatively Velcro your shirt to your underwear in a similar fashion to the jacket and trousers advice above

Comment: There is underwear like the baby suits for adults, mostly for women, but in practice many women do not want to fiddle with the poppers every time they have to tuck the 'shirt' in. There are also shirts with boxer shorts for male dancers, but I do not know how common those are.